# Perspective projection and rotation in python

Tags: python, rotation, projection, perspective

I've tried searching but none of the other questions seem to be like mine. I'm more or less experimenting with perspective projection and rotation in python, and have run into a snag. I'm sure my projection equations are accurate, as well as my rotation equations; however, when I run it, the rotation starts normal, but begins to swirl inwards until the vector is in the same position as the Z axis (the axis I am rotating over).

```
''' Imports '''
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, TclError
from threading import Thread
from math import cos, sin, radians, ceil
from time import sleep

''' Points class '''
class pPoint:
    def __init__(self, fPoint, wWC, wHC):
        self.X = 0
        self.Y = 0
        self.Z = 0
        self.xP = 0
        self.yP = 0
        self.fPoint = fPoint
        self.wWC = wWC
        self.wHC = wHC

    def pProject(self):
        self.xP = (self.fPoint * (self.X + self.wWC)) / (self.fPoint + self.Z)
        self.yP = (self.fPoint * (self.Y + self.wHC)) / (self.fPoint + self.Z)

''' Main class '''
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Declarations '''
        self.wWidth = 640
        self.wHeight = 480

        self.fPoint = 256

        ''' Generated declarations '''
        self.wWC = self.wWidth / 2
        self.wHC = self.wHeight / 2

        ''' Misc declarations '''
        self.gWin = Tk()

        self.vPoint = pPoint(self.fPoint, self.wWC, self.wHC)

        self.vPoint.X = 50
        self.vPoint.Y = 60
        self.vPoint.Z = -25
        self.vPoint.pProject()

        self.ang = 0

    def initWindow(self):
        self.gWin.minsize(self.wWidth, self.wHeight)
        self.gWin.maxsize(self.wWidth, self.wHeight)

        ''' Create canvas '''
        self.gCan = Canvas(self.gWin, width = self.wWidth, height = self.wHeight, background = "black")
        self.gCan.pack()

    def setAxis(self):
        ''' Create axis points '''
        self.pXax = pPoint(self.fPoint, self.wWC, self.wHC)
        self.pXbx = pPoint(self.fPoint, self.wWC, self.wHC)
        self.pYax = pPoint(self.fPoint, self.wWC, self.wHC)
        self.pYbx = pPoint(self.fPoint, self.wWC, self.wHC)
        self.pZax = pPoint(self.fPoint, self.wWC, self.wHC)
        self.pZbx = pPoint(self.fPoint, self.wWC, self.wHC)

        ''' Set axis points '''
        self.pXax.X = -(self.wWC)
        self.pXax.Y = 0
        self.pXax.Z = 1
        self.pXbx.X = self.wWC
        self.pXbx.Y = 0
        self.pXbx.Z = 1
        self.pYax.X = 0
        self.pYax.Y = -(self.wHC)
        self.pYax.Z = 1
        self.pYbx.X = 0
        self.pYbx.Y = self.wHC
        self.pYbx.Z = 1
        self.pZax.X = 0
        self.pZax.Y = 0
        self.pZax.Z = -(self.fPoint) / 2
        self.pZbx.X = 0
        self.pZbx.Y = 0
        self.pZbx.Z = (self.fPoint * self.wWC) - self.fPoint

    def projAxis(self):
        ''' Project the axis '''
        self.pXax.pProject()
        self.pXbx.pProject()
        self.pYax.pProject()
        self.pYbx.pProject()
        self.pZax.pProject()
        self.pZbx.pProject()

    def drawAxis(self):
        ''' Draw the axis '''
        self.gCan.create_line(self.pXax.xP, self.pXax.yP, self.pXbx.xP, self.pXbx.yP, fill = "white")
        self.gCan.create_line(self.pYax.xP, self.pYax.yP, self.pYbx.xP, self.pYbx.yP, fill = "white")
        self.gCan.create_line(self.pZax.xP, self.pZax.yP, self.pZbx.xP, self.pZbx.yP, fill = "white")

    def prePaint(self):
        self.vA = self.gCan.create_line(self.wWC, self.wHC, self.vPoint.xP, self.vPoint.yP, fill = "red")

    def paintCanvas(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.ang += 1
                if self.ang >= 361:
                    self.ang = 0

                self.vPoint.X = (self.vPoint.X * cos(radians(self.ang))) - (self.vPoint.Y * sin(radians(self.ang))) 
                self.vPoint.Y = (self.vPoint.X * sin(radians(self.ang))) + (self.vPoint.Y * cos(radians(self.ang)))
                self.vPoint.pProject()

                self.gCan.coords(self.vA, self.wWC, self.wHC, self.vPoint.xP, self.vPoint.yP)

                self.gWin.update_idletasks()
                self.gWin.update()

                sleep(0.1)
        except TclError:
            pass

mMain = Main()

mMain.initWindow()
mMain.setAxis()
mMain.projAxis()
mMain.drawAxis()
mMain.prePaint()
mMain.paintCanvas()
```

Thank you for any input :)

EDIT: Sorry, I just realized I forgot to put my question. I just want to know why it is gravitating inward, and not just rotating "normally"?

Comment: You're seeing the effect of accumulation of floating point errors, since `self.vPoint` is derived from its old value, but using inexact floating point numbers. You need to orthogonalize the matrix frequently to prevent these errors getting out of hand.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I should, say every time theta returns to 0 degrees, reset X and Y back to their original magnitudes?

Comment: Or, don't compute vectors based on their old vectors at all.  Only have one or two angles computed from their old values, where the accumulation of floating point errors doesn't matter.  Then recompute all vectors from these angles.

Answer (score 1):

This section is wrong:

```
self.ang += 1
if self.ang >= 361:
    self.ang = 0

self.vPoint.X = (self.vPoint.X * cos(radians(self.ang))
               - self.vPoint.Y * sin(radians(self.ang))) 
self.vPoint.Y = (self.vPoint.X * sin(radians(self.ang))
               + self.vPoint.Y * cos(radians(self.ang)))
self.vPoint.pProject()
```

For two reasons:

1. `self.ang` will take integers in the open range [0 - 360], which means the angle 360 (== 0) is repeated.
2. In each iteration, you rotate the point from the *previous iteration* by the angle. As a result, your first frame is at 1 degree, your second at 1+2 = 3, the third at 1 + 2 + 3... You should either be:

   - rotating the point from the previous iteration by a constant angle each time (1°). This suffers from the problem mentioned in my comment
   - rotating the *initial* point by the current angle of rotation each time

Comment: Option 2.1 (rotating initial point) is correct. If your object doesn't change, but so do the angle, then perform the rotation always on the "baseline position" object instead of incrementally rotating it (it accumulates integration errors). The computational cost is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not actualy related to your problem, but I strongly suggest you to use Numpy to perform geometric transformations, specially if it involves 3D points.

Below, I post a sample snippet, I hope it helps:

```
import numpy
from math import radians, cos, sin

## suppose you have a Nx3 cloudpoint (it might even be a single row of x,y,z coordinates)
cloudpoint = give_me_a_cloudpoint()

## this will be a rotation around Y azis:
yrot = radians(some_angle_in_degrees)

## let's create a rotation matrix using a numpy array
yrotmatrix = numpy.array([[cos(yrot), 0, -sin(yrot)],
                          [0,         1,          0],
                          [sin(yrot), 0,  cos(yrot)]], dtype=float)


## apply the rotation via dot multiplication
rotatedcloud = numpy.dot(yrotmatrix, pointcloud.T).T   # .T means transposition
```

Comment: How would one effectively scale this up to larger point-clouds? I thought about simply increasing the dimensions of `yrotmatrix`, but I'm not sure how to scale the corner values to the zeros in the middle.

Comment: @DexterMorgan I'm not sure I understand your doubt. Typically "scaling up"  would only mean you have a larger `pointcloud` (an Nx3 matrix with a narger N), and one would expect the operation to take longer, but I don't believe it would take that much longer except for exceedindly large pointclouds (say, millions of points). Also I didn't understand what you mean by "scale the corner values to the zeros in the middle". Anyway you would never need a larger `yrotmatrix`, since it HAS to be a 3x3 matrix by definition.

Comment: I did not mean anything with regards to performance, rather: how would the rotation matric look if the point cloud was say 10x10?

Comment: Well that is an interesting question. My answer assumes a pointcloud in 3D space as being an Nx3 matrix where N is the point count, and 3 are the dimensions (x,y,z). When write of a 10x10 point cloud, that could mean two things: either a set of 10 points with 10 dimensions (coordinates) each, which I find unlikely, or a 10x10 array of 3D points. In the latter case, you would use `numpy.reshape` to make it into a 100x3 array. In the former case, you would need a 10x10 rotation matrix. But I wonder what would be the practical meaning of a 10-dimensional point space.

Comment: I am interested in rotating some images via this approach, so I have e.g. (100, 100, 3) RGB array. Would reshaping, rotating and shaping back even make sense? ... regarding your last point: Maybe something involving string theory could find a use for so many dimensions :)

Comment: @DexterMorgan take a look at [`scipy.ndimage.interpolate.rotate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) function!